# Displaying sublass model name in Rails form helper shared by subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance

Given these models:

```
class Person
end

class Man < Person
  def edit 
    @person     = Man.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :template => "man_form" } }
    end
  end
end

class Woman < Person
  def edit 
    @person     = Woman.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :template => "woman_form" } }
    end
  end
end
```

Then in each form I create a 'select' of 'characteristics' using this helper method that is shared by all:

```
def person_select(person, options)
  select :person, "characteristics", options
end
```

How would I make this so that when it's called by one of the subclasses (Man or Woman), it creates the select name with the that model name, instead of the parent 'person'?

So, I want to be able to call:

```
person_select(@man_object, {...})
```

and get:

```
<select name="man[age]" id="man_age">
...
</select>
```

The reason I need to do this is so that when the form is submitted I can get params[:man] form the man_controller or params[:woman] from the woman_controller and be able to work with those specific object types, and not 'person'.

I could get the class name and do:
select person.class.to_s.underscore but then it doesn't use the object anymore, so the passed object won't be selected in the list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can ask which class it belongs to and then call the name of that class.

```
$ Post.first
=> #<Post id: 1>
$ Post.first.class
=> Post(id: integer, title: string)
$ Post.last.class.name
=> "Post"
```

What confuses me is that you have a `@man_object` so obviously the object is a man and that means you could just have two helpers assuming you would also have a woman object:

```
man_select(@man_object, {...})
woman_select(@man_object, {...})
```

And then your `select_fields`

```
def man_select(person, options)
  select_tag :man, "characteristics", options
end 

def woman_select(person, options)
  select_tag :woman, "characteristics", options
end
```

But if you did not know if it was a man or woman:

```
man_select(@person, {...})
```

Then your select_tag:

```
def person_select(person, options)
    if person.class.name = "Man"
        select_tag :man, "characteristics", options
    else
        select_tag :woman, "characteristics", options
    end
end
```

Comment: But then it doesn't have the object, so if it's in edit mode it won't make that object selected in the list. I'll edit the post to spell that out as well.

Comment: If you have a `@man_object` why do you need to know if it is a `Man`? Isn't that implied?

Comment: Can you conceptually explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Or even better provide code explaining how you are getting the `person` object. Such as your array, or whatever.

Comment: OK, I updated the post with what is hopefully the information you wanted. Thanks.

Comment: TO answer your question "If you have a @man_object why do you need to know if it is a Man?" -- b/c if I pass a man_object the way it is now it creates the select with name="person["age"], then the controller gets a 'Person' and not a 'Man'.